# setvisibility:gone cannot be resolved to a variable

Tags: android

I want to hide the polls, but set Visibity:gone is not working. If I add a parameter for View. It is giving an error saying

> type mismatch:cannot convert from void to boolean.

```
public void setInitialScreenDesign() {
    switch (LaunchPadConstants.loginnDetails.getLoginType()) {
    case LoginDetailsMgr.LOGINTYPE_STUDENT:
        StudentLeftFragment studentLeftFragment = (StudentLeftFragment) LaunchPadUtilities.getFragment(this, R.id.home_left_frag);
        if (studentLeftFragment != null) {
            if (studentLeftFragment.pollLinearLayout.setVisibility(GONE))
            {
                //... do something
            }
            else
            {
                //... do something else
            }
        }
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Visibity:gone is not working.If I add a parameter for View.It is saying an error saying type mismatch:cannot convert from void to boolean.    if (studentLeftFragment.pollLinearLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting visibility of a view in 'if' condition which is incorrect, there should be a boolean value in if statement. However you can do something like this to get your job done:

```
if(studentLeftFragment.pollLinearLayout.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)
{
   studentLeftFragment.pollLinearLayout.setVisibility(GONE);
   ...
   ...
}
```

Comment: thank you @prashant patel for your valuable inputs.It worked for me

Answer (score 0):

> type mismatch:cannot convert from void to boolean

Because [View.setVisibility](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVisibility%28int%29) return `void` instead of `boolean`.

To check is view visibility use `View.getVisibility()` which return one of `View.VISIBLE(0)`, `View.INVISIBLE(4)`, or `View.GONE(8)`